# image align is not working even after using style1

Tags: html, css

Image not getting aligned and near image label should come but its not working correctly

```
<style>
    label{
         color:red;
         font-family: "Times New Roman";
         font-size: 25px;
    }
    label.desc{
         color:blue;
         font-family: "Times New Roman";
         font-size: 12px;
          position: relative;
         left: -20px;

    }
    img{
        float:left;
        width:300;
        height:300;

    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of layout..? `image | blah1 | image | blah2 | image | blah3` Just confused a bit..

Comment: what is your current CSS behaviour? show us in jsfiddle.

Comment: You have shown screenshot in which images are well aligned.
You are asking for creation of CSS, but you are showing us CSS code.  I am not getting your question.

Comment: its sample page sir and i want to do my page similarly like that

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8azyh/

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/8azyh/2/. r u looking something like this?

Comment: @NandhiniDevi http://jsfiddle.net/8azyh/4/ what about this..? Built using pure ul elements, and hard coded the height as 189px since your image has the same.. Edit this according to your need..

Comment: it was useful for me @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 1):

Put every image and corresponding labels in a div like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <image src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Heart.gif"/>
    <label>1<label>
    <label>2<label>
    <label>3<label>
</div>
```

and give that div width:

```
#a{
    width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You don't have to be rude, dude! I would write this as a comment but I dont have enough reputation for that.

Comment: No i am not reacting ruder here.. Just tried to get a perfect answer for the OP.. Just make your post clearer, i am sure, i'l remove the downvote from your post.. :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure the file extension is .css and not .txt

You may be hiding your file extensions. Check http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7

Then put this:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

between the

```
<head></head>
```

tags in your HTML file to call your stylesheet.

Make sure to rename "style.css" with whatever you name your new stylesheet.